# MVC C3 What is the proper format for inheriting a class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have created the following class, it describes any type of file that may be uploaded by a user:

```
namespace MyModels.Models
{
    public class File
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileTypeId { get; set; }
        public string URLFileName { get; set; } //cleaned for web
        public string Dir { get; set; } //which directory is located in
        public long FileSize { get; set; } //size in bytes
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; } //date uploaded
        public int UploadedByUser {get; set;} //UserID of user
        public bool inCloud { get; set; } // moved to cloud
        public bool inGlacier { get; set; } // moved to glaciers
        public DateTime? DateTrashed { get; set; } //date user deleted
        public int TrashedByUser { get; set; } //UserID of user
        public List<FileDescendent> Descendents { get; set; } //List of copies
    }
}
```

I then want to create a class for just image files. I want this class to have the file properties as well. Do I do this?

```
namespace MyModels.Models
{
    public class Image : File
    {
        public int OrigHeight { get; set; }
        public int OrigWidth { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Or this?

```
namespace MyModels.Models
{
    public class Image
    {
        public int OrigHeight { get; set; }
        public int OrigWidth { get; set; }
        public File File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What is the difference please?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is an object design question in general, rather than being specific to MVC3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28computer_science%29). In this case image **is a** file.

```
public class Image : File
{
    public int OrigHeight { get; set; }
    public int OrigWidth { get; set; }
}
```

This is a [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). In this case image **has a** file.

```
public class Image
{
    public int OrigHeight { get; set; }
    public int OrigWidth { get; set; }
    public File File { get; set; }
}
```

As for me, image is a file. Thus inheritance is more appropriate here.

Comment: Thanks this is a very clear answer. ANd conceptually I can understand the difference now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is in the API. Would you rather look up inCloud as `image.inCloud` or `image.File.inCloud`?

In most cases, I'd prefer `image.inCloud`. However, if File is expensive to instantiate, for example, the second accessor pattern might be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your response as well! They're all very helpful. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is inheritance, the second example is not.

In your second example you will have the file properties also, but bundled in the `File` property. To access the `FileName` property for example, you would use `obj.File.FileName` instead of `obj.FileName` that you get when you inherit the class.

Also, as `File` is a property in the `Image` class, it won't automatically get created when you create an instance of the `Image` class. You also have to create an instance of the `File` class and put in the `File` property of the `Image` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with inheritance. It would allow you to use dependency injection models for both. Something that is very useful with MVC3.

the second big advantage, is that you can have shared views that display lists of Files, and you would be able to pass in collections of both types. Not to mention any Linq your write.